# How to write a program from scratch in C# using EmguCV

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, emgucv

I am trying EmguCV 2.2.1 in Visual Studio 2010 Express (C#)
All the examples given with the Emgu Installation work absolutely fine, and give the desired output.
But when i write a program myself, an exception is thrown at me even before running:

**TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code.
The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.**

I have included ALL the references required for running the program.
I have also tried to copy the SAME "working" example to another location and compiling it again, and the project still does not run...
I have tried copying the DLLs into the exe directory... Still no result...

Help me... Please...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that all opencv dlls are in the execution directory and that MSVCRT is installed to resolve dll dependencies. The MSVCRT installer (vcredist_x86.exe) is supplied with the emgucv download or you  can visit [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en).